Vectorize NFFT python
I am using the nfft package for non-equispaced Fast Fourier Transform in python. My question is really simple actually : is there a way to vectorize the function of the package ?
For example, I defined the following function
from nfft import nfft_adjoint
import torch
import numpy as np
def NFFT(x_points, f_noneq, N):
    """Function that performes the non-equidistant fast fourier transform"""
    normalized_x = normalize(x_points) #just a function to normalize input data 
    f_python = nfft_adjoint(normalized_x.numpy(), f_noneq.numpy(), N = N) #here we perform the NFFT
    return torch.tensor(f_python)

However, the inputs for the function nfft_adjoint is only 1D. In torch or numpy, we can specify the dimension i  which to perform the FFT. I was looking to implement this technique in my NFFT function.

Have you tried writing a loop over the remaining dimensions?

Yes, this is suggestion will work. The problem is that looping is not optimal. For example in torch or numpy, we can perform ffts ins a single direction of a matrix only by specifying the dimension that we want to perform the operation. For example : torch.fft.fft(input, dim=-1) will apply the FFT in the las dimension of a matrix.

“Not optimal”. Who cares? Write the loop, get your computations done. If it turns out to be too slow for your application (ie the application is not meeting performance requirements and this loop is a bottleneck according to the profiler), then you can worry about how to speed up the loop. There’s a good chance it doesn’t matter, and you’ll have saved yourself a lot of work and time by not worrying about being optimal. Google “premature optimization” and read to learn what other programmers have learned from experience.

By the way, NumPy and Torch functions loop internally. Those loops are written in a compiled language, so they’re faster than a loop written in Python, but they’re still loops. If the work done inside the loop is sufficiently expensive, then the overhead of looping in Python is irrelevant.

I see your point.  I did implemented using loop and it works fine, but not for my application in terms of time. When I am using a matrix that is (512, 512, 1000), my function takes about 17 seconds when using FFT with torch (applying in the way that I wrote above).  However, applying the NFFT function over each coordinate (y,x,1000) (in the last axis) takes way more time then expected ( the prevision is more then 3 hours) !

So I do believe that my implementation is not going to work if I use the function nfft_adjoint from the library nfft in the particular manner that I presented here.  Looping it over the index of my matrix did not reach  a satisfactory performance in terms of time.  I know that there are some other libraries that allow the use of nfft and maybe that would be the way to go

If it takes that long, the looping overhead is minuscule. NFFT is much more expensive than FFT, that’s why it takes longer.

For example, take your loop and replace the call to NFFT with something trivial like np.sum. The loop should finish in a very short time. Whatever this time is, that is the overhead of the loop. All the other time is spent doing the NFFT computation. You can only get around that by finding a better implementation of the NFFT, or by changing your algorithm so it doesn’t need an NFFT.

I was just now looking at the source code for nfft.nfft(). If you use the same x input to all the calls in the loop, you could modify the code so that the nfft_matrix is computed only once. I don’t know how large a fraction of total computation this is, but it makes sense that you’d save time.

Idea to consider: some simple interpolation to make samples equispaced, then standard FFT will be good enough and faster?
